# GitHub CLI can't login

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to login to the GitHub cli tool using `gh auth login` as per the docs (https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login). However, I keep getting this error:
`gh: error: unrecognized arguments: auth login`

Additionally, I get an unrecognized arguments error for most commands. For example, if I try run `gh repo view`, I get `gh: error: unrecognized arguments: repo view`. I have installed gh using brew and I have already run `brew update` and `brew upgrade gh`.

Comment: What does `man gh` show? Have you installed the correct tool?

Comment: Also, what version are you running?  Check `gh --version`.

Comment: `man gh` says that I've installed `gh - GitHub CLI` with the description `Work seamlessly with GitHub from the command line.` One of the examples it gives me in the man page is `gh repo clone cli/cli`, but when I run this I get `gh: error: unrecognized arguments: repo clone cli/cli`

Comment: I have `gh version: v0.0.4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved it. I had installed a version of `gh` using pip and another version using Brew. The pip version was `0.0.4` which meant I didn't have access to any commands. I used `pip uninstall gh` and then reinstalled with Brew which did the trick